# create a trigger in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I need to create a trigger that, before deleting information about producers from the table Producers will replace prod_id in table Films on prod_id + 1. My current code :

```
    CREATE TRIGGER increment_prodid_before_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON Producers
BEGIN
    UPDATE Films SET prod_id = prod_id + 1 WHERE prod_id = (SELECT prod_id FROM Producers);
END;
```

[Here is image of my tables][image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

The subquery:

```
SELECT prod_id FROM Producers
```

returns all the `prod_id`s of the table `Producers`.

What you need is the `prod_id` of the deleted row and you can get it with `OLD.prod_id`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_prodid_before_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON Producers
BEGIN
    UPDATE Films 
    SET prod_id = prod_id + 1 
    WHERE prod_id = OLD.prod_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you need tot do that , doesn't look like a wise solution for whatever problem you are trying to solve. but to answer your question here is how you can do it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_prodid_before_delete 
BEFORE DELETE ON Producers for each row  
BEGIN
   UPDATE Films SET prod_id = prod_id + 1;
END;
```